# Cut a string/url to always get a final string/url with a specific data and it's value in php

Tags: php, string, while-loop

I have an url that contain the word "&key".
The "&key" word can be at the beginning or at the end of our url.

Ex1= http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx&c2=xxx&c3=xxx&key=xxx&c4=xxx&f1=xxx

Ex2= http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx&key=xxx&c2=xxx&c3=xxx&c4=xxx&f1=xxx

What I would like to get is all the time the url with the Key element and it's value.

R1: http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx&c2=xxx&c3=xxx&key=xxx

R2: http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx&key=xxx

Here is what I have done:

```
$lp_sp_ad_publisher = "http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx&c2=xxx&c3=xxx&key=xxxc4=xxxf1=xxx";
$lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link = explode("&", $lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut[1]); // tab
$lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link_final = $lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link[0]; // http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx
$counter = 1;
// finding &key inside $lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link_final
while ((strpos($lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link_final, '&key')) !== false);
{
    $lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link_final .= $lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link[$counter];
    echo 'counter: ' . $counter . ' link: ' . $lp_sp_ad_publisher_cut_link_final . '<br/>';
    $counter++;
}
```

I'm only looping once all the time. I guess the while loop isn't refreshing with the inside new value. Any solution?

Comment: Do you really intend to remove parameters which occur after the key param? Or do you just want to make sure the key is the last param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT***: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

This is tricky because the url key and value can be anything, so it might be safer to breakdown the URL using a combination of [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), then put the url back together leaving off the part you don't want. Something like this:

```
function cut_url( $url='', $key='' )
{
    $output = '';
    $parts  = parse_url( $url );
    $query  = array();

    if( isset( $parts['scheme'] ) )
    {
        $output .= $parts['scheme'].'://';
    }
    if( isset( $parts['host'] ) )
    {
        $output .= $parts['host'];
    }
    if( isset( $parts['path'] ) )
    {
        $output .= $parts['path'];
    }
    if( isset( $parts['query'] ) )
    {
        $output .= '?';
        parse_str( $parts['query'], $query );
    }
    foreach( $query as $qkey => $qvalue )
    {
        $output .= $qkey.'='.$qvalue.'&';
        if( $qkey == $key ) break;
    }
    return rtrim( $output, '&' );
}
```

Usage:

```
$input = 'https://www.xxxxx.com/test/path/index.php?c1=xxx&c2=xxx&key=xxx&c3=xxx&c4=xxx&f1=xxx';
$output = cut_url( $input, 'key' );
```

Output:

```
https://www.xxxxx.com/test/path/index.php?c1=xxx&c2=xxx&key=xxx
```

Comment: This is great however, I need also the beginning of the url. Not only the value for 'key'

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to validate your answer but I used a différent methode to do it =)

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to always ensure that the parameter `key` and it's associated value appear at the end of the string, how about something like:

```
$tmp=array();$key='';
$parts=explode( '&', parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY ) );
foreach( $parts as $pair ) {
    list( $param,$value )=explode( '=',$pair );
    if( $param=='key' )$key=$pair;
    else $tmp[]=$pair;
}
$query = implode( '&', array( implode( '&', $tmp ), $key ) );
echo $query;
```

or,

```
parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $pieces );
foreach( $pieces as $param => $value ){
    if( $param=='key' ) $key=$param.'='.$value;
    else $tmp[]=$param.'='.$value;
}
$query = implode( '&', array( implode( '&', $tmp ), $key ) );
```

### update

I'm puzzled that you were "not getting the good result"!

consider the url:

```
https://localhost/index.php?sort=0&dir=false&tax=23&cost=99&aardvark=creepy&key=banana&tree=large&ac=dc&limit=1000#569f945674935
```

The above would output:

```
sort=0&dir=false&tax=23&cost=99&aardvark=creepy&tree=large&ac=dc&limit=1000&key=banana
```

so the `key=banana` gets placed last using either method above.

Comment: I'm working on your first solution. with $parts=explode( '&', 'http://xxxxx.com?c1=xxx&c2=xxx&c3=xxx&key=xxx&c4=xxx&f1=xxx'); I'm not getting the good result